# Subsetting and assigning data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, variable-assignment

I am uncertain on what happens in a specific type of data subsetting and assignment in R.

Suppose I have a two column dataframe, where the first column is the name of a month and the second column is some data. I will just do a simple example here but the actual rows in the dataframe I am working is much bigger.

```
x <- data.frame(c("october", "march", "february", "january"), rnorm(4), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(x) <- c("months", "value")
```

Is it safe to subset and set values to the data in the following manner?:

```
x[x[,1] == "october",1] <- "01/10"
```

I ask this because I do not fully understand what happens in the case no match exists in the first column, for example:

```
x[x[,1] == "december",1] <- "01/12"
```

x[x[,1] == "december",1] returns:

```
> x[x[,1] == "december",1]
[1] months value 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Why does R accept an assignment to something that doesn't exist? I do not understand  clearly what happens in this case and I am worried some unforeseen assignment or behavior could happen.  Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: x[,1] returns a dataframe. Use the drop=TRUE argument also to make it a vector

Comment: you might also want to specify which column you want to insert "01/10" into right? else it gets copied to both the columns

Comment: I just corrected that @joel.wilson

Comment: `x[x[,1] == "december",1]` : in this case, `x[,1] == "december"` returns c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE) right. which means select no rows. Therefore nothing gets replaced

Answer (score 2):

> Why does R accept an assignment to something that doesn't exist?

I don't know what other behavior you'd like to see. If you want to get a heads-up when no rows are modified, one way would be with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)

x[ months == "december", months := "01/12", verbose = TRUE ]
```

which gives...

```
Creating new index 'months'
Starting bmerge ...done in 0.02 secs
Detected that j uses these columns: months 
No rows match i. No new columns to add so not evaluating RHS of :=
Assigning to 0 row subset of 4 rows
```

Note that the last two lines tell you that no rows were modified.

If you are somehow writing this console output to a text file log, then you can scan it to figure out if there were any instances matching "Assigning to 0 row subset". It also might be possible to get stats on rows modified through an "auditing" package like [Jan Gorecki's dtq](http://jangorecki.github.io/blog/2015-06-03/dtq.html).

---

*How this syntax works:*

The syntax for [the data.table package](http://r-datatable.com) is `DT[where, select|update|do, by]`. In this case, we are making an "update" and skipping the `by` argument. I recommend the "Getting Started" page if you choose to use the package.

Comment: it makes sense if the right-hand side is not evaluated in the expression:`x[x[,1] == "december",1] <- "01/12`
since there is no element in the first column of the dataframe with december.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the intrinsics of what happens, what goes on "under the hood"

Comment: @Rafolks Let me know if something in particular is unclear. If you want a better understanding of data.table, going through the vignettes in order is a great way to start: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Frank, so in the expression `x[x[,1] == "december",1] <- "01/12"` the right hand side doesn't  get evaluated?

Comment: @Rafolks No, it does get evaluated there, I'm pretty sure. You'll need to use data.table syntax if you want to avoid the evaluation. Follow the link in the final paragraph for tutorials; it's a little different from what you're doing.